# convert td to dt and dd

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to convert tables.
I would like to convert the first cell "td" into "dt" and the second cell into "dd" of each row.
I've tried it, but do not know howto different the first and the second cell.

**Source**

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td class="dl"></td>
    <td class="dl"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Target**

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <dt></td>
    <dd></dd>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**xsl**

```
<xsl:when test="@class='dl'">
  <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dt>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="@class='?'">
  <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dd>
</xsl:when>
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Can a `tr` contain other `td` elements, besides the two shown?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `<xsl:choose>` in which you test the *position* of the `td`. If it's 1, output `dt`, else output `dd`:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@class='dl'">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
            <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dt>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dd>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="@class='?'">
      <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dd>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

> **Function:** *number* **position()**
>
> The **position** function returns a number equal to the context position from the expression evaluation context.
>   (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)

Slightly more readable without nested `xsl:choose` (and more logical, since you only want to process `td class="dl"` anyway):

```
<xsl:template match="td[@class='dl']">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dt>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/></dd>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I only get the dd element. The dt is ignored.
I copied your code exactly. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Olli: this **definitely** works for your sample input and output. Note that I had to invent a large part of the XSLT - your fragment is by far not a complete working example and maybe you made an error elsewhere. Also, which of my solutions did you try? (In case you did not notice, I gave 2 of 'em.)